# subplot() takes 1 or 3 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Нужно вывести 100 тренировочных изображений на график, вот код:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from mnist import *
import tensorflow
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
mnist.temporary_dir = lambda: '/tmp'

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
assert x_train.shape == (60000, 28, 28)
assert x_test.shape == (10000, 28, 28)
assert y_train.shape == (60000,)
assert y_test.shape == (10000,)

fig, ax = plt.subplot(10, 10)

# Изображаем каждый снимок в Ч/б прячем оси
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        ax[i][j].imshow(x_train[10 * i + j], cmap='Greys')
        ax[i][j].xaxis.set_visible(False)
        ax[i][j].yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Но при запуске получаю ошибку об аргумента, не совсем пойму что не так и как ее поправить

```
  File "/home/kirill/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    fig, ax = plt.subplot(10, 10)
  File "/home/kirill/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1287, in subplot
    key = SubplotSpec._from_subplot_args(fig, args)
  File "/home/kirill/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/gridspec.py", line 594, in _from_subplot_args
    raise TypeError(f"subplot() takes 1 or 3 positional arguments but "
TypeError: subplot() takes 1 or 3 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому как `subplot()` и `subplots()` - это разные функции.
Для вашего случая правильная запись

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(10, 10)
```